# error: crypto.createHash is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, cryptojs, password-encryption

I'm using crypto for password encryption but when I try to call the function. I'm getting the following error.
[Warning of crypto.createHash method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6HKf.png)
You can find the following code:

```
import crypto from 'crypto';

export const encrypt = (text: string) => {
    const algorithm = 'aes256';
    const key = crypto.createHash('sha256')
        .update(String(reactApp))
        .digest('base64')
        .substr(0, 32);
 // some calculation
    return encrypted;
};
```

I've tried to use crypto-browserify but it's showing some more errors as you can see below.
[crypto-browserify error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDdrS.png)

When I run the given command as it suggests, it shows me another error which says the repository doesn't exist. Moreover, it show me this error too.
[polyfill](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VxdD.png)

I've tried to add this code in the webpack.config.ts file too.

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            crypto: 'crypto-browserify',
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX , I have made the changes in the code. I'm calling this encrypt function with passing a string, thus returning an encrypted string and saving it somewhere. Please consider reactApp is a string that is declared in my .env file. I'm doing some calculation in between with key and algorithm.

Comment: However, the questions you've asked is not aligned with what I'm asking.

Comment: Fair enough ... thought at least fixing `createHash('sha256')` would fix the only error you described - oh, wait ... you're trying to use a node builtin in a browser? that won't work - use [subtleCrypto](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) instead - you'll have to refactor your code a bit, since subtleCrypto is mostly Promise based

Comment: The benefits of using subtle crypto is that is it available in nodejs as well